# coredump directly when new operator

Tags: c++, out-of-memory, new-operator

I think it will: catch except when some error about 'new' happens (eg: oom...)
but it core dump directly at 'new' operator every time.

```
char* buf = NULL;
try {
  buf = new char[100]; // core at this line every time
} catch (std::bad_alloc& ba) {
  printf("bad_alloc, errmsg[%s]", ba.what());
}
```

also try do not use new like below:

```
char buf[100] = {0};
```

it core dump too!

Comment: if you corrupt memory previously (delete pointer twice for example), it can blow up in your face later when you allocate\deallocate memory

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The issue may be at other lines of code, as AndrewKashpur said above.

Comment: Why do you insist on C-isms like `NULL` (prefer `nullptr`) and `printf` (prefer iostreams) in a C++ program? Also; avoid using `new`/`delete` - use containers and smart pointers instead - we are not in the 90's any more ;-)

Comment: its some codes of a big old project, and the project has no problem in machine with Linux version 2.6.32_1-15-0-0 ; but it coredump at machine with Linux version 3.10.0_3-0-0-15. gdb can know it core at that new operator

Comment: Have you used `valgrind` or address sanitizer? This smells like you've corrupted your heap somehow.